# How can I make matplotlib titles searchable?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am producing a few hundred matplotlib plots, I work in Jupyter Notebook. Each have it's own title. I want to be able to search for these titles. So when I download the file as html, and open it in browser, I'd like to find the title via using ctrl-f. How can I do that?

---

More details, here is an MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=range(5);y=range(5)

for i in range(6):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title("Title"+str(i))
```

This produces nice plots, titled Title0 Title1 ... Title5. Howevere, these titles are part of the file and not searchable by ctrl-f, or browser doesn't detect them as text, though it would be desired.

I can do it in gnuplot but now I'd like to stick to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate markdown within a Jupyter notebook. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown('Title of graph goes here'))
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black');
```

Edit: I've just realised that in your example all the titles will be printed before the graphs. The solution is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# DO NOT USE %matplotlib inline
x=range(5);y=range(5)

for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.figure()
    _ = plt.plot(x,y)
    title = "Title"+str(i)

    display(Markdown(title))
    display(ax)
```

Comment: I am editing my answer as it won't work well for multiple plots. The key is to not use %matplotlib inline and explicitly display the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You may `print` title for every figure (`plt.show()` necessary in this case):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=range(5);y=range(5)

for i in range(2):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title("Title"+str(i))
    print("Title"+str(i))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: good, but in some cases when I have many plots, it prints all the title together and then the plots, maybe its my machine, but otherwise good